# Saving the state of Android fragment while switching the orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can we retain the state of the fragment while changing its container.

I am trying to change the container of the fragment while switching from portrait to landscape. And I am getting IllegalStateException saying "cannot change the container id of the fragment ABC". Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragmet onSaveInstanceState(...) as explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I am using __onSAveInstanceState__. Here is my code  

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  if(isDualPane)
  {
   getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "imageDownloadFragment", imageDownloadFragment);
   getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "imageShowFragment", imageShowFragment); 
  }
  else
  {
   getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "imageDownloadFragment", imageDownloadFragment);
  }
  
 }

Comment: Problem is that When I replace the saved instance of the fragment with the container, it gives my this exception. "cannot change the container id of the fragment from say 123 to 124".

Comment: Have you declare the fragment inside the layout file as a <fragment ...> tag? If so, please use a FrameLayout to attach your fragments by using the fragment manager.